# How to get the right selectedText position when touch the textView?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, caret

I want to get a position where user touch the textView, then convert it to the position of view in UIViewcontroller. I used following code:

```
if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
       let react = textView.caretRect(for: selectedRange.end)
       let viewReact = view.convert(react, from: textView)
  }
```

The problem is the position sometimes is right ,sometimes is wrong. Why would that happen?

Comment: I think you should check, has the touch been clicked at textView or some another view.

Comment: You better read this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

Comment: ok, I will try it